# Pre image of compact is closed & continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let the function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R }$ be bounded on bounded set have the property that $ f^{-1}(K)$ is closed whenever $K $ is compact . prove  $f$ is continuous

We known that if pre image of closed set is  closed then $f$ is continuous

I take $F$ closed set in $\mathbb{R}$   need to prove   $ f^{-1}(F) $  is closed

Set is closed  if its complement is open    how to proceed  further

Comment: $R = \mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a restriction $f:[i,i+2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Since $f$
is bounded on bounded set, then we can assume that $f :
[i,i+1]\rightarrow [a,b]$. For any closed set in $[a,b]$, it is
compact set. Hence preimage of $f$ is closed. Hence the restriction
is continuous. This holds for all $i$ so that $f$ is continuous on
$\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain two arguments.

Elementary one: consider a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ converging to a point $x$. Our aim is to show that $L:=\{\textrm{limit points of}\,\, \{f(x_{n})\}\}$ equals $\{f(x)\}$. First,  since $\{x_{n}\}$ is bounded, so is $\{f(x_{n})\}$. Then Heine-Borel theorem tells us that $L$ is nonempty.

Now take any subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ of $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $f(x_{n_{k}})$ converges to a value $l$. Then $K_{M}:=\{l\} \cup \{f(x_{n_{k}})\}_{n=M}^{\infty}$ is a compact set, so its preimage $f^{-1}(K_{M})$ is closed. Thus, $x$, the limit point of $\{x_{n}\} \subseteq f^{-1}(K_{M})$, also belongs to $f^{-1}(K_{M})$. Sending $M \rightarrow \infty$, we conclude $f(x) = l$. Thus, any element of $L$ equals $f(x)$. This ends the proof.

Fancier words: given a closed set $K$, we consider $K_{r} = K \cap ([-r-1, -r] \cup [r, r+1])$: $\{K_{r}\}$ are compact sets such that $\cup_{r} K_{r} = K$. We know that $f^{-1}(K_{r})$ is closed for each $r$. Although union of arbitrary closed sets need not be closed, union of locally finite collection of closed sets (it means that inside any bounded set, you see only finitely many such closed sets) is closed in general. Since $f$ sends bounded sets to bounded sets, $\{K_{r}\}$ are indeed locally finite and $K = \cup_{r} K_{r}$ is closed.